# Can I customize the speech recognition words using HTML5 and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to capture the scientific words in my program. For example buccal,furcation..etc..

I have to match the word and I have to execute the method...I am not getting the scientific words or medical terms in speech recognition. How can I get scientific or medical terms in speech recognition ?
I am doing speech recognition by using the following link.

https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

Comment: This is pretty vague. :(

Comment: After reading the specification and going through a few pages, it seems to be impossible for now as too much of the API is under specification.